# Python program to calculate average quiz grade for students

Tags: python

Ok, it I don't understand where I am going wrong because I had help with this coding and for the person who originally wrote it, it works just fine. However, mine seems to be malfunctioning. It keeps displaying the 'highest grade' multiple times instead of just once like it's supposed to. Having some real newbie problems here.

This is the code:

```
#this program will compute average quiz grade for a group of 5 students
#prompt user for quiz grade using a for loop for each of the 5 students

#assign names to student list
students = ["John", "Jake", "Jane", "Sally", "Susie"]

#grades: 90-100=A, 80-90=B, 70-80=C, 60-70=D, <60=F


#prompt user for student grades
grades = []
for student in students:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))
    grades.append(grade)


sum = 0
for i in range(0,5):
    for i in grades:
         sum+=i
avg_grade=sum/5


#print average grade of students
if(avg_grade >=90):
    print("Average Grade: A")
elif(avg_grade>=80 and avg_grade<90):
    print("Average Grade: B")
elif(avg_grade>=70 and avg_grade<80):
    print("Average Grade: C")
elif(avg_grade>=60 and avg_grade<70):
    print("Average Grade: D")
else:
    print("Average Grade: F")



#print highest grade
max_grade=max(grades)
for i in grades:
    if(max_grade>=90):
        print("Highest Grade: A")
    elif(max_grade>=80 & max_grade<90):
        print("Highest Grade: B")
    elif(max_grade>=70 & max_grade<80):
        print("Highest Grade: C")
    elif(max_grade>=60 & max_grade<70):
        print("Highest Grade: D")
else:
    print("Highest Grade: F")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `for` loop at the end, which means for every single grade, the highest grade will be printed out.

You can delete the `for`, and unindent the `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements. Then the program should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of using a variable such as sum, because sum is a python special function, you should use something like total.

Second, you shouldn't be using `eval(input())` because the eval does nothing.

Third, when doing the for loop, you don't already know the number of students so it should be `for i in range(len(students)-1)` and the `-1` part because list indexing starts at 0. Also, the second for loop should use a different variable then `i` because `i` is already used, so use something like `j`.

Comment: "Sum" can be used as a variable name.

Comment: well i mean the uppercase variable sum could be used but people still might mix it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use just sum to get the total grade and average value. Don't need to run an additional loop for 5 times.

```
total = sum(grades)
avg_grade = total/len(grades)
```

Then you don't need to run a loop to get the highest grade and also else should be indented with like other `if elif`. Follow the code

```
students = ["John", "Jake", "Jane", "Sally", "Susie"]

grades = []
for student in students:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))
    grades.append(grade)


total = sum(grades)
avg_grade = total/len(grades)


if(avg_grade >= 90):
    print("Average Grade: A")
elif(avg_grade >= 80 and avg_grade < 90):
    print("Average Grade: B")
elif(avg_grade >= 70 and avg_grade < 80):
    print("Average Grade: C")
elif(avg_grade >= 60 and avg_grade < 70):
    print("Average Grade: D")
else:
    print("Average Grade: F")


max_grade = max(grades)
if(max_grade >= 90):
    print("Highest Grade: A")
elif(max_grade >= 80 & max_grade < 90):
    print("Highest Grade: B")
elif(max_grade >= 70 & max_grade < 80):
    print("Highest Grade: C")
elif(max_grade >= 60 & max_grade < 70):
    print("Highest Grade: D")
else:
    print("Highest Grade: F")
```

Comment: You shouldn't just post code that doesn't have any additional comments about what went wrong so that the asker can learn.

Comment: The comment was from user code, Ok I modified it

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sum = 0 
> for i in range(0,5):
>     for i in grades:
>          sum+=i 
> avg_grade=sum/5
> ```

what that does is essentially go through every grade and increment `sum` every time and do that 5 times. It's unnecessarily [O(n^2)](https://hackernoon.com/big-o-for-beginners-622a64760e2) and will run significantly slower when you add a lot of data.

Other than that a couple of useful things were pointed out by the other answers, I think one of them directly put the code there too so there isn't much I can say.

Basically you had [logical flaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error) in your code that caused it to not function as intended.

### **debugging**:

[image: debugging]

as you can see above the values for `sum` and `avg_grade` are totally not what they're intended to be, this was uncovered using print statements in the right places.

Your logic in implementation was flawed for the next part too, but this post is already too wordy for it's purpose.